# PS3 Slim 4.55 No Display, No Video, No Audio

Tags: ps3, hard-drive

I have a PS3 Slim 120 GB. I just updated to 4.55, and it got stuck while restarting the system. I force shut it down, and in doing so, I corrupted the hard drive. Now, I do not have any display (I tried HDMI and the AV adapter), and I can't even get into Safe Mode after following  the appropriate steps. After removing the hard drive from the PS3, I see the error message that the media storage cannot be found, so I know that my hard drive is corrupted.

But now, I can boot into safe mode by following the steps **without the hard drive**. I made a USB flash drive with the 4.55 update, so is there a way for me to possibly put the PS3 hard drive in while safe mode is still displayed on the screen, and then restore the update that is on my flash drive to the hard drive? Or can I put the hard drive in while safe mode is running and then restore the file system?

Comment: The problem with storage devices, is that they're not hot-swappable, except for server grade ones. My tip would be to format the drive on your PC if possible (make sure you format it correctly; the PS3 only recognizes FAT32 formatted partitions), put it back into your PS3, and try again. If that doesn't work, try another HDD if available.

Comment: Can you recommend any software to transfer the Save Data on the hard drive to the computer?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any.

Comment: You should be able to just pull your data off by taking the folders, if you can navigate through the hard drive anyway. I never tried that when I did mine since I was able to back it up before and upgrade. Guess you learned the hard way when it says not to turn off during an upgrade, that it means it.

Comment: Yes, I did. The only "solution" was to buy a Sata 2.5 inch to USB adapter, remove the hard drive from the PS3, connect it to a Linux-based computer, and reformat the drive. Then, I put it back into the PS3, correctly formatted a USB drive to PS3 4.55, and reinstalled the entire OS.